# Got an error while upgrading CentOS

Tags: centos, upgrade, subversion

I'm upgrading my server but an error occurred. Here is the error report:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  package subversion-1.6.15-0.1.el5.rfx.x86_64 (which is newer than subversion-1.6.11-7.el5_6.4.i386) is already installed
  file /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/psvn.el from install of subversion-1.6.11-7.el5_6.4.i386 conflicts with file from package subversion-1.6.15-0.1.el5.rfx.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/subversion.mo from install of subversion-1.6.11-7.el5_6.4.i386 conflicts with file from package subversion-1.6.15-0.1.el5.rfx.x86_64
  file /usr/share/xemacs/site-packages/lisp/psvn.el from install of subversion-1.6.11-7.el5_6.4.i386 conflicts with file from package subversion-1.6.15-0.1.el5.rfx.x86_64
```

Comment: ...and your question is?  It looks like someone installed a newer version of subversion already; it's probably harmless (if this server is not used for hosting something subversion-related in which case you possibly need to be a bit more careful).

Comment: Did none of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You already have a version installed.

You can try to clean using

```
rpm -e --nodeps --allmatches <packagename>
```

This will erase all packages that match the packagename and not check the dependencies before it does.  After that you should be able to yum update successfully.

Comment: tks. problem solved :D

Comment: *Never* use `--nodeps`, you are creating an inconsistency!

Comment: Absolutely agree with @vonbrand. -1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

This means that a newer version of the package than the one in the upgrade is already installed. This should work right if you tell the upgrade to use the updates for the upgraded version.

In any case, CentOS really doesn't need to be upgraded explicitly during a series. That is, if you originally installed CentOS 5.0 and updated rigurously, by the time CentOS 5.2 comes out you already have that installed through package updates. CentOS 5.2 just rolls all the updates into one installable set. You'd need to upgrade when CentOS 6.0 comes out, or upgrade directly to, say, CentOS 6.2.